# domain of a function $f(\sin(x)) = \sin^2(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

what's the domain of f where
$$ f(\sin(x)) = \sin^2(x)$$
is the domain $\mathbb{R}$ or[-1,1]
I say it's $\mathbb{R}$ since there's no constraint on x to be real, the constraint is on
sin(x) to be real so x can be complex thus sin(x) is real

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you are not stating (or you are missing altogether) crucial pieces of information. I don't exactly understand the reason why $\sin$ should tacitly be assumed to be a map $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, while $f$ should be assumed to be a function from a subset of $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. My guess would be that all the functions appearing in the text are implicitly assumed to be $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, and therefore that nothing can be said about the domain of $f$, other than the fact that $\operatorname{dom}f\supseteq [-1,1]$.

Comment: saying $f(x) = x$ I didn't specify the domain but Intuitively we say it's mapped from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ same here I'am trying to get $f$ to be real, so choosing sin(x) to be complex will get that

Comment: @IbrahimAbouElenein At this level of question I don't quite care about intuition or intuitive explanations: I only care about reading the pieces of information that I know I need to know.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of question is ill-posed; you can't deduce the domain of a function just from a functional equation that involves it.

Even if the equation $f(\sin(x))=\sin^2(x)$ is only given to hold for $x\in\Bbb R$, we might still have $\operatorname{dom} f=\Bbb R$ or even $\operatorname{dom} f=\Bbb C$. For $x\notin[-1,1]$, we simply have no information about $f(x)$ (including whether it is defined).